# Normally-on MOSFET configuration for turning off source voltage in the presence of another

Tags: voltage, power, mosfet, switches, integrated-circuit

I have two plugs on my board, one of which will take in +12 V, the other +5 V. They are both wired to the same load. If the +12 V is present, I want to prevent connection/driving by the +5 V, i.e. disconnect it.

Theoretical solution: I could theoretically use a p-channel depletion-mode MOSFET (if they exist, which [(it seems they don't)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/652863/alternative-to-depletion-mode-p-channel-mosfet-based-voltage-limiter), by connecting the MOSFET between the +5 V and the load, with the +12 V on the gate.

Is there a better (i.e. physically available) solution to this problem? Tangential solutions welcome!

Comment: p-channel depletion mode devices do exist, but they aren't commercially available. There's no reason they can't be made, there's just no demand for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can tolerate small forward (0.3V) diode drop, a pair of Schottky diodes would be a robust and available solution.

This would work like shown here ([simulate it](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgpABZsKBTAWjDACgBncGmkYwkGjx8BVCADMAhgBsODTt15DB%20FcKpUps%20QCVFa8GBQGNtKklMwEbPWB4jDx-lBc0xxy9GvZe4gO4AJgBOAPYADgA6AI4w9BCE0HjMYJ4INMQ0hAS4kMTYeawq4GwBghhOAthoDsb%20weHRsWx%20Bs6YFVDNBsrtJmxBtIS8dryZw8QeyJBsAOaD48ZjJp0tVVTO2NgCztOr1cqbAsq7IIcGZ0bqXRcowkuXK-Pgt08jjzfCZztsYRRGz8IEP8wBNwC4TvcXkDjA8IUNwKDoQiPCUysYDvtVLVAqFIjFoNg2EA)):

[image]

This is a 'diode power-or' circuit. The common connection will take on the higher of the two voltages, less the forward diode drop. When 5V is present, the output will be ~4.7V; with 12V present the output will be ~11.7V.

The challenge with using MOSFETs would be to achieve a smooth changeover from your lower (5V) rail to the higher (12V) rail. There are ICs (e.g., Analog Devices 'Powerpath') that can handle this.

---

I describe a switchover circuit that could be used for +12 / +5 switching here: [What does this MOSFET do in this voltage regulation circuit?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/551195/what-does-this-mosfet-do-in-this-voltage-regulation-circuit/551196#551196)

Change as follows:

- FET path for +5
- Diode path for +12

Then it looks like this ([simulate it](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgoqoQFMBaMMAKACdwAWT8YlLnigSEoyeCwDmAkEJFhuMjPyqQWAd2lg%20mjCNUb5PMLt79jelgBNT4Eyk5VzM8ADkEGZiwBmisyjy%20IHhU2Njg0EhgCOoywkGOCsFQMZh%20AYbg-skGCmBZGU6qAEognAFJYCJJKqW0oioRLCVlmelyWTUOmfVQjRr2jiahcib6IMOt49hVKjETSf7lsxwTWvwTsqJg4hqr2qujklMimxtK9SzTAfMheDzV2ce2IqsdLADOpUvgefE9XgBDAA27zoHy%20k2YaS2IEBILBBl%20FUSs0R0IKb2wAWIIAAYhAakgmCAAGoAfQAQgBBAAqNMu6So%20J6RIg5IAqgBlCksIA)):

[image]

The benefit of this arrangement is reduced IR drop when 5V is in use. (I'll assume you don't care as much about this when in 12V mode.)

Comment: I think a 0.3V drop would be fine, do you have a reference for the technique you're talking about? I.e. how this might be connected and how it works?

Comment: Stated simply, tie the diode cathodes together to your internal power rail, tie one diode's anode to +5, and the other diode to +12. When +12 is present, its diode will be forward biased while the +5V one will be reverse biased.

Comment: really amazing answer, thanks a ton!